# How to pass values from external page to parent page in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, url

I have a problem that I wanted to solve for my client. i hope that I will explain it well.
let say that I have a JSP form with some fields of personal data and on same page is popoup button that opens another page with form that have fields for personal address to add in parent form page. The problem is that popup form came from external URL. How can I submit addres from child page to parent page?

Thank you in advance.

here is example what I ment

MyForm - Parent form page:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <input id="name" value ="John Smith" />

        <input id="billingCity" value=""/>
        ...

    </body>
 </html>
```

Address verifcation page:

```
<html>
    <body>

    <form action ="https://foo.com/HandleAddressValidationResults.jsp">
        <input id="city" value="Oregon" />

        ...
        <input type="submit" value="Accept" />
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does the external URL (or application) store the address anywhere ?

Comment: you can use the url query string

Comment: No it doesn't store anywhere it is in form. And thank you for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

This scenario is easily solved using JavaScript. `window.showModalDialog()` method

If you click the link below you will understand easily.

[Using Modal Window](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25388/Accessing-parent-window-from-child-window-or-vice/%22Modal%20Window%22)

For Example,

```
function openwindow()
{
    retval=window.showModalDialog("modaltarget.htm")
    document.getElementById('text1').value=retval
}
```

Comment: Thank you both you where very useful now I can see the solution more clear. Thank you again for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

in your parent page , when you call the child pop up page
suppose parent page is parent.jsp
and in the pop you are calling child.jsp
in your parent jsp , when you call the child page

```
window.location = ../child.jsp
```

pass some parameters

```
<script>
var value1 = document.getElementByID('name').innerHTML;
var value2 = document.getElementByID('billingCity').innerHTML;
window.location = "../child.jsp?param1="+value1+"&param2="+value2;
</script>
```

now these paraeters will be passed as request parameters
in your child.jsp pop up page
get values of param1,param2 ... and so on using request.getParameter()
and set the values in input fields in child.jsp

Comment: Thank you very much Hussain I will try that and see how it will do.